# Dual monitors -- Control from which edge the cursor appears at

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, mouse, cursor

Let me explain better. I have dual monitors. When I move my mouse toward the right edge on my primary monitor and then move it over the edge, the mouse appears on the **left** edge on the second monitor which is to the left of the primary monitor. I'd like the cursor to appear at the right edge of the secondary one when I move the cursor over the left edge of the primary monitor.

Is this possible?

I'm running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can tell Windows how your displays are oriented.

- Right click on the desktop and select "Screen resolution"
- In the upper box, showing the monitors, click and drag and arrange the displays to match the actual setup (you may want to click "Identify" so you know which one Windows thinks of as 1 and 2)
- Click OK

Things should work as expected then.

Comment: To add to this answer, I did not have to do anything else to make it feel right. Just fiddle with how high my landscape monitor is in relation to the portrait one to make them match reality. Took a little fiddling but working well. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Open the Control Panel

---

#### Category View

If you're in Category view, select 'Adjust screen resolution':

[image]

---

#### Or Classic View

If you're rockin' the classic view, open Display

[image]

Now select Adjust Resolution

[image]

---

You should see something like this:

[image]

Swap the two screens and click Apply.

Comment: "Swap the two screens" is a little ambiguous . . .

Comment: Genius!!! I had no idea you could do that. Thanks a lot. Sorry that I don't mark you as the correct answer seeing as you put so much effort into it. I decided to mark ernie as correct because he answered a bit before you. Thanks though.

Comment: @ernie Nothing a little hand drawn arrows and Comic Sans can't fix!

Comment: @Gudmundur His answer is actually quicker anyway. :)

Comment: Upvote from me, especially since the annotation looks like a smiley face ;)

Comment: @ernie Ahahaha I can never unsee that.