# Dual monitors issue

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two monitors. One on the left is a 2600 x 1440, and the one on the right 1920 x 1080. The left monitor is connected via the Displayport, which is monitor 1. The right monitor is connected via HDMI, and is monitor 2. The problem is that can't drag any application from left (monitor 1) to the right (monitor 2).

When I drag an application it stops when the cursor is at the boundary of monitor 1. Then I have to move the cursor to the other monitor and continue from there.

Need help in resolving the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Try dragging off the other edge of the monitor and see what happens.

Comment: What operating system is this?  Also, what video display adapters are involved?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/781489/dual-monitors-control-from-which-edge-the-cursor-appears-at?rq=1

Comment: Which OS, are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your monitors are simply reversed.

Assuming you're working on Windows (please EDIT your question to add this rather necessary information), right-click on your Desktop and select Display Properties.

In the dialog that opens, click the Identify button and observe the numbers projected on your displays.

Now, click and drag the monitor icons in the dialog so their numbers correspond to the actual layout of the monitors in reality.

Click OK/Apply.

Answer (score 0):

Go here:
Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution

Flip the monitors over with a click and drag and then tick the box 'Make this my primary display' to the monitor on the left (assuming thats where you want your desktop to be).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your monitor arrangement is flipped or just not set up properly.  In Windows 10, this is in Display Settings when you right click anywhere on the desktop.  The displays involved should appear on the field in the menu that it shows.  You can drag and drop these to set their arrangement, including slight adjustments to ensure the cursor is at an elevation which makes sense.

For example, my two 1680x1050 monitors at work are not on the same level.  One is portrait and stands next to a riser which has the other monitor set as landscape.  You can fine-tune the adjustments so that the cursor crosses over in a way that makes sense, which I have done by making cursor motions from halfway down my landscape monitor and below cross over to the top third of the portrait monitor.